# How to call shell file from .ts file?

Tags: typescript, bash, sh

I recently picked up a project where there is bash file which calls `.ts` file to get records. Now this `.ts` file is getting the data from simulator which is working but not sure how to pass that along to `shell` script.

i.e., In `loadData.ts`,line `console.log("records => ", records.length);` comes with some 500+ records. Now I want to pass this via `.sh` file so that line `console.log(${response.count} data loaded);` in `myTsFile.ts` shows up with data.

How to do that?

I tried with `child_process` (below snippet) but I don't think it is working. It just stops after 5 mins or so. Not sure if I am doing it right. If I run `./loadRecords.sh` in terminal then I get `0 data loaded` so that flow is working. I am missing pieces in `loadData.ts`.

Code:

loadRecords.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

npm run --silent myTsFile -- "$@"
```

myTsFile.ts

```
import {loadHistory} from "../loadHistory.js";

const request = {
  depth: options.depth,
  verbose: options.verbose
};
const response = await loadHistory(request);

console.log(`${response.count} data loaded`);
```

loadData.ts

```
#!/usr/bin/env ts-node

import { RecordRequest } from "./requests.js";
import { RecordResponse } from "./responses.js";
import { Simulator } from "simulator";
import { exec } from "child_process";

export async function loadHistory(request: RecordRequest): Promise<RecordResponse> {
  
  console.log("request => ", request.depth);
  
  const simulator = new Simulator();
  const allRecords = simulator.getAllRecords("123");
  console.log("allRecords => ", allRecords.length); // I can see records here

  // var records = exec('sh ./loadRecords.sh --depth 1',
  //   (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  //     if (error !== null) {
  //       console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
  //     }
  //   });

  var records = exec('bash loadRecords.sh --depth 1',
    (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error !== null) {
        console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
      }
    });

  console.log("records -> ", records);

  return { count: 0 };
}
```

Comment: `exec` is asynchronous. You need to either switch to a function like `execSync`, or use promises or callbacks to handle asynchronous responses.

Comment: @Evert I tried with `var records = execSync('bash loadRecords.sh --depth 1')` and `var records = execSync('bash loadRecords.sh --depth 1').ToString()` but same behavior. Can you provide an example here?

Comment: @Evert when I use `spawnSync`, I am getting `"errno":-2,"code":"ENOENT"` error.

Comment: `ENOENT` suggests that you tried to use a file which doesn't exist. But we can't debug your code just from the error message; please [edit] to include the code of your attempt.